# Override method of an existing instance

Tags: javascript, durandal, overriding, durandal-navigation

I'm trying to extend an existing Durandal router plugin instance already created with the help of RequireJS.

The method `map()` should be overriden to add extra mapping parameters.

How should I access the original method from the modified one?

**index.js**

```
define([ 'durandal/app', 'app/childRouter'], function(
        app, childRouter) {
    childRouter.map([ {
        route : 'details/:id',
        moduleId : 'details/index',
    }, {
        route : 'details/tabs/base',
        moduleId : 'details/tabs/base',
    } ]);
    childRouter.buildNavigationModel();

    return {
        router : childRouter
    };
});
```

**childRouter.js**

```
define([ 'durandal/app', 'plugins/router'], function(
        app, router) {

    var childRouter = router.createChildRouter();
    childRouter._map = childRouter.map;
    childRouter.map = function(data) {
        data.unshift({
            route : [ '', 'grid' ],
            moduleId : 'grid/index',
        });
        childRouter._map(data);//CALLS THE OVERRIDEN METHOD AGAIN INSTEAD OF ORIGINAL
    };
    return childRouter;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to still call the original "map" function, you'll need to store it before you overwrite it. It's a bit "hacky" to replace functions in this way, but if you REALLY had to do it, this will work:

```
var childRouter = router.createChildRouter();
childRouter.originalMap = childRouter.map;  // Save original
    childRouter.map = function(data) {
        data.unshift({
            route : [ '', 'grid' ],
            moduleId : 'grid/index',
        });
        childRouter.originalMap(data);    // Call original
    };
```

Comment: Tried it, but instead of calling the original `map()` it calls the overriden one again. I don't understand what's going on?

Comment: I need a small clarification: are you intending on calling the original map function inside of the overridden one? or do you want it callable just in general?

Comment: Yes exactly, it should be callable inside the overriden one. I found it works outside Durandal (for example when you create JSFiddle), but not inside. I tried debugging the sequence of in which the functions get called and found nothing unusual. I wonder why the function calls itself again instead of the stored original.